# UIButton slide in, instead of fade in

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I have a `UIButton` in a `UIViewController` that I currently have "fading in" to view when the app is opened.  **I would like to get the `UIButton` to slide in from left to right instead though.**

I can't figure out how to get it to slide in from left to right and my attempts have failed, even though I've got the "fade in" thing down solid.

Any help you could give me?  Thanks!  I can add any more code as needed-

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonOne;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        NSTimer *timermovebutton = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(movebutton) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [timermovebutton fire];
}

-(void) movebuttontwo
{
    buttonTwo.alpha = 0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:Nil context:Nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp];

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    buttonTwo.alpha = 1.0;

    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to animate the buttons frame, not use an animation curve.

Since iOS 4, we've had UIView animation blocks:

```
// first set the UIButton frame to be outside of your view:
// we are only concerned about it's location on the X-axis so let's keep all properties the same
[buttonTwo setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.view.frame), CGRectGetMinY(buttonTwo.frame), CGRectGetWidth(buttonTwo.frame), CGRectGetHeight(buttonTwo.frame))];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     // set the new frame
                     [buttonTwo setFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMinY(buttonTwo.frame), CGRectGetWidth(buttonTwo.frame), CGRectGetHeight(buttonTwo.frame))];
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }
];
```

There's a [good tutorial over at Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial) you can check out to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! It worked sliding it, but quick question also, my buttonTwo is W280xH60 and is centered, so how would I get it to move to that area of the ViewController, instead of right now it moves past center and hangs on the left side of the screen?

Comment: Just changed `setFrame:CGRrectMake(0` to `setFrame:CGRrectMake(20` and got it to work!  Last question, I was wanting the animation to move left to right, but it currently moves right to left, which value would I change for that?

Comment: Change the X coordinate for your CGRectMake (the first value). You should change the rect before you setup the animation to something like `-CGRectGetWidth(buttonTwo.frame)`, which means the button will start on the right of the frame with it's entire width out of the frame.

Comment: If you want to center your button just use `buttonTwo.center = viewController.view.center`

Comment: If I use `-CGRectGetWidth(buttonTwo.frame)`, the button comes in from right-to-left.  I need it to come in left-to-right, so I'm not sure what to set the `-CGRectGetWidth` for that?  Sorry I didn't explain it too well.

Comment: I recommend you go through the tutorial I linked to above which explain frame animation for UIView and more.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Set your button off the screen to the left
yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(-yourButton.frame.size.width, yourButton.frame.origin.y, CGRectGetWidth(yourButton.frame), CGRectGetHeight(yourButton.frame));

//Create the ending frame or where you want it to end up on screen
CGRect newFrm = yourButton.frame;
newFrm.origin.x = 100;

//Animate it in
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
    yourButton.frame = newFrm;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response!  It worked sliding it, but quick question, my buttonTwo is W280xH60 and is centered, so how would I get it to move to that area of the ViewController, instead of right now it stays on the right half of the screen?

Comment: Just change `newFrm.origin.x = 20;`?

Comment: Just calculate where x needs to be to make it centered on the screen. So your buttonX = (viewWidth / 2) - (buttonWidth / 2)

Comment: Awesome just got it to work!  One last question, I was wanting to go from left to right instead of right to left, which value gets changed for that?

Comment: Just update the first CGRect to instead of being -yourButton.frame.size.width its just the size of the view so it would be CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) in place of -yourButton.frame.size...

Comment: I now have this as the code for what I think you were telling me: `buttonTwo.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), buttonTwo.frame.origin.y, CGRectGetWidth(buttonTwo.frame), CGRectGetHeight(buttonTwo.frame));` but it still is sliding from right-to-left... am I reversing something still?

Comment: The code in my original answer should take the button from off the left side of the screen to the middle (left to right). The modification mentioned in the previous comment before yours will take the bottom from off the right side of the screen to the  middle (right to left).